# How to run kafka consumer asynchronously with python FastAPI

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, fastapi

I am using Kafka-python with FastAPI. I am able to run my consumer successfully but it is not allowing any other functionality to work. It gets stuck in the for loop for consuming messages. I want my consumer to run continuously and also want other functionalities to work.
How can I achieve this ?
In below code method isolve_kafka_consumer() starts running but when I make a post call it doesn't invoke my router and log_requests() method.

```
import os
from typing import List


from isolveconsumer.commonutils.base_logger import LoggerManager
from isolveconsumer.routers.application_router import application_router
from isolveconsumer.client.isolve_consumer_client import  IsolveConsumer
from isolveconsumer.configuration.read_secrets import set_env_variables
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn
import time
import random
import string
from datetime import datetime
import threading
from isolveconsumer.commonutils.isolve_trigger_utils import Constants, EnvironmentUtils, ConfigueParser, \
    ConfigConstants
LOGGER = LoggerManager().get_logger(Constants.ISOLVE_CONSUMER)
env = EnvironmentUtils.get_env_var(var_name=Constants.EPASS_ENV, default_value=Constants.LOCAL)
config = ConfigueParser()
LOGGER.info("Executing env is {}".format(env))

# Data from multiple sources is published as events for isolve
isolve_consumer = FastAPI(
    title="iSolveConsumer",
    description="This is the consumer for isolve",
    version="1.0.0",
)
# all routers
isolve_consumer.include_router(application_router, prefix="/isolveconsumers/v1", tags=["application"])

# kafka_consumer = None

@isolve_consumer.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    LOGGER.info("setting all the env variables required for iSolve")
    LOGGER.info("Starting app at {}".format(datetime.now()))
    set_env_variables()

@isolve_consumer.on_event("startup")
async def isolve_kafka_consumer():
    LOGGER.info("creating the isolve consumer for consuming messages")
    topic = config[env][ConfigConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC]
    group_id = config[env][ConfigConstants.KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP]
    bootstrap_servers: List[str] = config[env][ConfigConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS]
    LOGGER.info(f"List : {bootstrap_servers}")
    security_protocol = config[env][ConfigConstants.SECURITY_PROTOCOL]
    cafile = config[env][ConfigConstants.SSL_CAFILE]
    certfile = config[env][ConfigConstants.SSL_CERTFILE]
    keyfile = config[env][ConfigConstants.SSL_KEYFILE]
    password = os.environ.get("ssl_password")
    consumer = IsolveConsumer(topic, group_id,bootstrap_servers,cafile,certfile,keyfile,password,security_protocol)
    LOGGER.info(f"Consumer Object : {consumer}")
    consumer.isolve_events_consumer()

async def log_requests(request: Request, call_next):
    idem = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))
    start_date = datetime.now()
    start_time = time.time()
    LOGGER.info("Requests logged")
    if str(request.url).__contains__("/isolveconsumers/v1/health"):
        LOGGER.info("Entered Health")
        response = await call_next(request)
    else:
        LOGGER.info(f"rid={idem} start request path={request.url.path} start time={start_date}")
        response = await call_next(request)
        end_date = datetime.now()
        end_time = time.time()
        process_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
        formatted_process_time = '{0:.2f}'.format(process_time)
        LOGGER.info(
            f"rid={idem} completed_in={formatted_process_time}ms status_code={response.status_code} end time={end_date}")

    return response
#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("isolve_consumer:isolve_consumer", host="0.0.0.0", port=8084)
```

Comment: I'd suggest aiokafka library if you want asyncio features for Kafka clients

Comment: Okay will try that. But it means kafka python can never run asynchronously ? What if I run them on separate threads or process ? Will this approach affect performance or any of the functionalities of kafka ?

Comment: aiokafka can do just as much as any other Python client. Last I checked, kafka-python is completely blocking and relies on its own Future class rather than integrate natively with asyncio. Sure, you can wrap it with your own custom thread classes, but I feel like that's unnecessary when there's other ways around that, and considering you've not shown `IsolveConsumer` class, I'm not sure I understand what issues you're having

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with FastAPI, but I don't think you can have more than one annotation for `.on_event("startup")`, and you've defined `log_requests` function but it's never referenced anywhere